# try..catch then rollback the already run stored prod in .net c# web application

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications

Does anyone know, how can I rollback the already run stored prod inside try...catch in .net c#?

Example:

If I have 2 stored proc need to be run, 2 function is created to run each of the stored prod, and those function will be call inside the try...catch, the 1st stored prod run successfully, however the 2nd stored prod having an error and timeout. In this case, any way I can rollback the 1st stored prod in my .net c#?

Comment: you going to have to use transaction statement. not sure about stored procs- might have to modify them.. something like this http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/10/14/2515.aspx   or this  http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/080305-1.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

```
private static void DemoFunc() 
   {
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("");//conection string here
      SqlTransaction transaction;
      SqlCommand cmd;

      conn.Open();
      transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
      try 
      {
         cmd = new SqlCommand("MySP1", conn, transaction);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

         cmd = new SqlCommand("MySP2", conn, transaction);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         transaction.Commit();
      } 
      catch (SqlException sqlError) 
      {
         transaction.Rollback();
      }
      conn.Close();
   }
```

Hope this help.